# Looking for the best way to export and import a variable between modules

Tags: javascript, export, appcelerator, commonjs

So I am working with learning CommmonJS using Appcelerator and I am trying to figure the best way to use a variable from one module (which is an array) in a my ui module. My issue is that in my ui module I have the main window(globally) for the ui and I have an eventlistener on a button that calls a function (in the same module) that opens a map. This map needs the variable that I getting from the previous module. Just not sure what is the best way to do this. Any advice would be awesome.

Data.js

```
var read = function(){
console.log("---read is activated---");
var db = Ti.Database.open('fourSqDB');
var rows = db.execute('SELECT fourSqID, name, lat, lng, distance, type FROM fourSqTBL');
var dbArray = [];
while (rows.isValidRow()){
    var record = {
        fourSqID: rows.fieldByName('fourSqID'),
        name: rows.fieldByName('name'),
        lat: rows.fieldByName('lat'),
        lng: rows.fieldByName('lng'),
        distance: rows.fieldByName('distance'),
        type: rows.fieldByName('type'),
    };
    dbArray.push(record);
    rows.next();
}   
rows.close();
db.close();

var getUI = require('ui');  //go into ui.js
//getUI.buildUI(dbArray); //fire buildMainUI function
getUI.buildSecUI(dbArray); //fire buildSecUI function

return dbArray; }; //close read function
```

ui.js

```
    var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    layout: "vertical",
    backgroundColor: "#ccc"
    //background: "images/bg.png"
});

//Navigation Window
var navWin = Ti.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow({
    window: win,
});

var label1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    //top: 250,
    textAlign: "center",
    text: "This is the shisha app created by Emmanuel Farrar for AVF1512 Week 3 assignment "
});

var labelButton = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: "Go To Data",
    color: "white"
});

var statementView = Ti.UI.createView({
    borderColor: "black", borderRadius: 10,
    top: 10, bottom: 0,
    height: 300, width: 350
});

var buttonView = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor: "#1f2f34",
    top: statementView.bottom + 200,
    borderRadius: 10,
    height: 75,
    width: 350

});

///////////////////////////////////////////
// buildSecUI function (map and listing)
///////////////////////////////////////////

var buildSecUI = function(dbArray){    //dbArray from data.js read function
    console.log("---buildSecUI is activated---");
    console.log(dbArray);

    var secWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    layout: "vertical",
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff"
    });

    //building the map
    var Map = require('ti.map');

    var mapView = Map.createView({
    mapType: Map.NORMAL_TYPE,
    region: {latitude:25.2867, longitude:51.5333,
            latitudeDelta:0.05, longitudeDelta:0.05},
    animate:true,
    regionFit:true,
    userLocation:true
    });

    //array for annotations (pins for maps)
    var annotations = [];

    for ( var i = 0 ; i < dbArray.length; i++ ) {
    // this section will create annotations and add them on the mapView
        var pin  = Map.createAnnotation({
            latitude: dbArray[i].lat,
            longitude: dbArray[i].lng,
            title: dbArray[i].name,
            type: dbArray[i].type,
            animate:true,
            pincolor:Map.ANNOTATION_PURPLE
        });

        annotations[i] = pin;
        //annotations.push(pin);

   // console.log(annotations[i]);
    console.log("Pin Info: " +  + "Lat" + pin.latitude + " / " + "Lng "+ pin.longtitude);

    mapView.addAnnotation(annotations[i]);  // adds annotations   
    }   //for loop closure

    secWin.add(mapView);
    navWin.openWindow(secWin);

}; //closure for buildSecUI

exports.buildSecUI = buildSecUI;

//event listner
buttonView.addEventListener("click", buildSecUI); //closure for buildSecUI

// adding stuff here
statementView.add(label1);
buttonView.add(labelButton);
win.add(statementView, buttonView);
navWin.open();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should go the other way.

In `data.js` export the `read` function but leave out the two `getUI` lines.

```
exports.read = function() {
  // your code except the two getUI lines
  return dbArray;
};
```

Then in `ui.js` require the `data` module, call the exported `read()` and build the UI with it.

```
var data = require('data');
var dbArray = data.read();
buildSecUI(dbArray);
```

This way you the `data` module is unaware of where and how its used (as it should be).

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Maybe this will resolve my new issue

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured what the problem was though like most things it just identified another problem, lol. In this case it worked to turn the whole thing into a function and move the .openWindow method to the event listener as its own function.

```
buttonView.addEventListener("click", function(){navWin.openWindow(secWin);});
```